# Executing setup.exe /silent via MSI File

Tags: active-directory, deployment, msi

I would like to build an MSI file for Active Directory deployment.  Instead of taking a pre install snapshot, installing the application, taking a post install snapshot and packaging the differences in an MSI file.  I would like to put a setup.exe file inside a MSI file and run it with the /silent switch.

Is there any free or cheap programs that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows Installer Wrapper Wizard](http://n.ethz.ch/student/heim/msi/WIWW_0-0-0-1.zip) will do what you want. It's scant on documentation and you should test the heck out of anything you make with it.